Spring message not recognised correctly in other languages except English
In cds-messages.properties we have defined the message
409003=''{0}'' is a required field (*).

For the same in error-messages-label-mapping.properties file we have defined the variable names
name=Program Name
type_id=Evaluation Type

So, the final error messages appearing in UI are
'Program Name' is a required field (*).
'Evaluation Type' is a required field (*).

Similarly we have defined for other languages as well, but in other languages the variable names are not correctly replaced. Below is an example for german language
409003=„{0}“ ist ein Pflichtfeld (\*).
name=Programmname
type_id=Auswertungsart

output:
„name“ ist ein Pflichtfeld (*).
„type_id“ ist ein Pflichtfeld (*).

the name and type_id is not replaced by their german labels given.
Only in English, it is working and in other languages it is having issue as above mentioned.
Also, we have defined it in application.yaml file as below
spring:
 application:
  name: evaluation-service
 messages:
  basename: "cds-messages,error-messages-label-mapping"

If the error-messages-label-mapping.properties file was altered like
instead of this annotation
„{0}“
if we give annotation like in English
''{0}''
then it works.
But we must not change the files given by translation team, so what change is required for the system to read those special characters particular to each language.

Some additional info is needed:

Which version of Spring are you using? Java version?
Have you confirmed that all relevant files are included in the classpath?
Try to force encoding on applicaiton.yaml to UTF-8


@Ghost93, we use Java 17 version and spring 3.0.16. Tried hard encoding also with UTF-8, didn't work

have you read the docs regarding this? Have you configured it properly? Read the note regarding default language properties file.

Yes the configuration is correct. Even tried with setting alwaysUseMessageFormat to true as per the message properties
